# How to use the fontawesome correctly

Tags: css, font-awesome

I am new, and I had to create an account to help me.

I have a forum, and I want to add a font-awesome icon to the range, but it does not describe or read it to me, I will leave images.
[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRLLv.jpg)

Code

```
.adm:before {
    content: "\f0e7";
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.adm {
    background: #d6351c;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgb(214, 53, 28), 0 0 2px rgb(214, 53, 28);
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: 6px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    padding: 4px 6px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#Add a unique CSS class name to the icon element you want to use.
#Set the font-family to “Font Awesome 5 Free” (For regular,solid icons)
#Set the font-weight css property as 900 (For Solid), 400 (Regular or Brands), 300
#Set the content css property to the ***unicode*** value font awesome icon.
#And if required,add a common CSS class name for all icon elements, for example “font-awesome-icons” (This is to add your own CSS to the icons).

eg

```
<span class="font-awesome-icons point"></span> Login
</li>


.point::before {
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Brands"; 
    font-weight: 400;
    content: "\f09a";
}
```

Comment: <span class="adm">Administrador</span><span class="fundador"> Fundador</span>
Hi!

I have that in the name of the range so that I can identify the css, which I have as ".adm"

Answer (score 0):

```
<span class="adm">Administrador</span><span class="fundador"> Fundador</span>
```

Hi!

I have that in the name of the range so that I can identify the css, which I have as ".adm"